# Visual studio c# font coloring

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to tweak the color of my font for c# in visual studio 2012.

observe the following code

```
if (condition)
{
    int test;
}
```

By default the characters

> (){}test;

Were all white. I want to make them grey. When I change the settings "Plain text" in fonts and colors settings, on the (){}; change, the word test does not.

If I change the "Text" color in font and colour settings, it additionally does nothing.

What value do I have to change to change the color of a variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the color values for *Identifier*. Other areas of interest are *Keyword*, *Literal*, and *Comment*, as well as *Number*, *String* and *Operator*, and any of the various *User type* that might be applicable to your code.

Comment: What is the name of the color for "///" comments. It seems to be different.

Comment: XML Doc covers the `///` stuff. It's for XML documentation generation.